# How can I merge two events to a selector?

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery codes that I want works separately fine. My question is that is there a way of putting then together as one and still work?

```
$('#truck_brand').poshytip({className: 'tip-yellowsimple', showOn: 'focus', alignTo: 'target', alignX: 'right', alignY: 'center', offsetX: 5});
$('#truck_brand').focus(function() { $('#brand_error').poshytip('hide'); });
```

Comment: You aren't working with two events, you're working with one event handler (`focus`) and a method that looks like it instruments a tool-tip. You can't merge these without access to the source code, and you wouldn't want to in any case--they do completely different things.

Comment: What do you mean by putting them together? Like a method chain? See http://schier.co/blog/2013/11/14/method-chaining-in-javascript.html

Comment: @Palpatim it is great confirming that both can't work as one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
$('#truck_brand').poshytip({className: 'tip-yellowsimple', showOn: 'focus', alignTo: 'target', alignX: 'right', alignY: 'center', offsetX: 5}).focus(function() { $('#brand_error').poshytip('hide'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always cache the jQuery instance of one or many dom elements:

```
var $truckBrand = $('#truck_brand');
$truckBrand.poshytip({className: 'tip-yellowsimple', showOn: 'focus', alignTo: 'target', alignX: 'right', alignY: 'center', offsetX: 5});
$truckBrand.focus(function() { $('#brand_error').poshytip('hide'); });
```

`.focus` also allows you to chain an additional call to the jQuery instance:

```
$('#truck_brand')
   .focus(function() { $('#brand_error').poshytip('hide'); })
   .poshytip({className: 'tip-yellowsimple', showOn: 'focus', alignTo: 'target', alignX: 'right', alignY: 'center', offsetX: 5});
```